# Authorize.Net Transaction details not being saved

Tags: prestashop, authorize.net, prestashop-1.6

I've installed and configured the free Authorize.net module from Prestashop, and have the module in test mode. I can put through payments, as expected, and the status in the back end is updated. And Authorize.net is returning the expected response.

The only problem I'm having now is that the transaction details are not being saved. I've done some debugging, and the problem seems to be that the first thing that happens when then `setTransactionDetail()` method is called, is that it's checking `if (isset($this->pcc))`, and in my case it's not, so it's not writing the transaction details to the database.

So I guess my question is what do I need to do to get $this->pcc to be set? It's not referenced in the code anywhere other than in this one single method. Am I missing some option in the back end? My PayPal module saves the transaction ID as expected, so it's not all payment modules that are being affected.

Comment: When you have the gateway in test mode, it doesn't actually perform a transaction.  Instead, it only validates the credentials and returns OK.  Instead, you should run in live mode.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I have the Prestashop module in test mode, not Authorize.net (using credentials from Authorize.net sandbox). Unless you're saying that the Prestashop module won't write the response when it's in Test mode? That would seem strange, because I am definitely getting the correct response from Authorize.Net, but something in the module is blocking it from writing to the database. Seems odd that it wouldn't test as many aspects of the transaction as it can when in test mode....

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Prestashop module, but if your endpoint is at test.authorize.net* then try setting the module to live mode instead of test mode.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue is with the module. I will try it with live credentials tomorrow though.